# calling a function after ComponentDidMount in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I want to call a function after componentDidMount () but also before render () .

-I want something like this

```
 render()- componentDidMount()- myFunction()- render()
```

Comment: I believe that componentDidUpdate should do the work. You can check on react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate . You have to cause and state or props change to use this.

Comment: just add setTimeout(myFunction, 0) as last line in componentDidMount :) BTW read reactjs lifecycle. Due to componentDidMount will only called when the component is mounted next you will be called to componentDidUpdate

Comment: What is ultimate aim to call it before rendering? Are you trying to intercept the requests for logging or other things?

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted, in another word when your component is mounted the render method is already called, so there is no space between componentDidMount and render. But what is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

The *componentDidMount* event already does that. Component's setup lifecycle behaves like this: constructor runs > render() is called > componentDidMount() is called > then another render() is executed. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this, please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can call a function in the constructor that will be called BEFORE a render()
you can call a function inside the componentDidMount, that will be called after the component is mounted (it will call some renders before and after)
Or you can call a force update inside your function to trigger a render.
More info on the React Component docs

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html